# Convert json to dynamically generated protobuf in Java

Tags: java, protobuf-java, protocol-buffers

Given the following json response:

```
{
    "id" : "123456",
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "email" : "john.doe@example.com"
}
```

And the following *user.proto* file:

```
message User {
    string id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    string email = 3;
}
```

I would like to have the possibility to dynamically create the protobuf message class (compile a .proto at runtime), so that if the json response gets enhanced with a field `"phone" : "+1234567890"` I could just upload a new version of the protobuf file to contain `string phone = 4` and get that field exposed in the protobuf response, without a service restart.

If I were to pull these classes from a hat, I would like to be able to write something along the following code.

```
import com.googlecode.protobuf.format.JsonFormat;
import com.googlecode.protobuf.Message;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

...

public Message convertToProto(InputStream jsonInputStream){
    // get the latest user.proto file
    String userProtoFile = FileUtils.readFileToString("user.proto");

    Message userProtoMessage = com.acme.ProtobufUtils.compile(userProtoFile);
    Message.Builder builder = userProtoMessage.newBuilderForType(); 
    new JsonFormat().merge(jsonInputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), builder);
    return builder.build();
}
```

Is there an existing com.acme.ProtobufUtils.compile(...) method? Or how to implement one? Running a protoc + load class seems overkill, but I'm willing to use it if no other option...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot compile the `.proto` file (at least not in Java), however you can pre-compile the `.proto` into a descriptor `.desc`

```
protoc --descriptor_set_out=user.desc user.proto
```

and then use the `DynamicMessage`'s parser:

```
DynamicMessage.parseFrom(Descriptors.Descriptor type, byte[] data)
```

Source: [google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/jy9bQKd7H10)

Comment: Just wanted to double check, if the byte[] data contains more fields than whats initially described in the .proto file would the parsing fail?